# invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem - Not ZFS

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-20.04, raspberry-pi4, microk8s

When running `microk8s.kubectl describe node ubuntu` I am getting the following error

```
Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      2m54s  kubelet  invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Normal   Starting                 2m54s  kubelet  Starting kubelet.
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      2m42s  kubelet  invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Normal   Starting                 2m42s  kubelet  Starting kubelet.
  Normal   Starting                 2m30s  kubelet  Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  2m30s  kubelet  Node ubuntu status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      2m30s  kubelet  invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      2m18s  kubelet  invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Normal   Starting                 2m18s  kubelet  Starting kubelet.
  Normal   Starting                 2m5s   kubelet  Starting kubelet.
```

When describing pod - I get the following error `Warning  FailedScheduling  30s (x33 over 41m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/not-ready: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.`

From what I know I am not running ZFS on my Raspberry Pi 4 - but I have a 128gb sd card with an ext4 filesystem. I have tried this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370710/microk8s-node-not-ready-invaliddiskcapacity) - but I don't have a ZFS pool....

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Did you remove [taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)? Also can you provide output of `$ df -Bm`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing cgroups...

### Raspberry Pi/ARM

Running MicroK8s on some ARM hardware may run into difficulties because cgroups
(required!) are not enabled by default. This can be remedied on the Rasberry Pi
by editing the boot parameters:

```
sudo vi /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
```

Note: In some Raspberry Pi Linux distributions the boot parameters are in
`/boot/firmware/nobtcmd.txt`.

And adding the following:

`cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1`
to address disk performance issues often present on Raspberry Pi see the troubleshooting section.

More details are available at: https://microk8s.io/docs/install-alternatives#heading--arm

Comment: can lvm be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

my master node is no ready and get the event

```
Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      15h   kubelet          invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
```

I restart my containerd, then the master node is ready.

```
systemctl restart containerd
```